# Choosing right Sleep state

Tags: arduino-uno, led, sleep

I'm planning on building an LED clock, but I want it to be lit only when I press the POWER button on my remote control. Using an IR receiver, which Arduino sleep mode should I use to reduce the current consumption but still be able to receive this interrupt?

Comment: Please be aware that, if you are using an Arduino board -ie you did not build your own- then you have a minimum consumption that you cannot reduce, e.g. due to voltage regulator current leakage, or (for UNO) ATmega16u2 is always running (for USB handling).

Comment: Also the IR-receiver uses something like a milli-amp. And then there is the power-on led.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Thank you I'm aware of that but at least I can consume a little bit less during the whole day.

Comment: You can drive the vcc directly by-passing the on board linear regulator. You can directly drive it with 2(2.8v), 3(4.5v) or 4(6v) for AA's. Note the ATMEGA328 is 6v and TSOP38238 is 2.5 to 5.5v

Comment: Related question has an [answer by me](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9862/ir-receiver-interrupt-and-arduino-sleep-mode) with example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading [ArduinoSleepCode](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode). Where it demonstrates placing the avr into a sleep state and using an interrupt to awake from the sleep state. In your case you can connect the output of your IR demodulator to the interrupt  pin, to simular awake.

Ken Shirriff's IR library allows you to use any pin as a receive input, so that you can use INT0 or 1 on D2 or D3. If you need to use a different pin, the Microtheron's github fork uses Pin Change interrupts. (I am not sure if stock sleep.h will awake from PCint, like int0 or 1 will, without tweek. Section 10.1 of data sheet says it will.)

Comment: You can only wake from INT0 and INT1, and only using the LOW trigger-mode; no PCINTs. The only problem is staying awake for a moment, while all the IR data is coming it, as the library you propose uses timer1 to sample the data coming in.

Comment: @Gerben I didn't think of that, while I'm pressing for the first time the POWER button the Arduino is still sleeping so it could miss some data, am I right?

Comment: Note the bootloader from any reset typically takes 5 seconds before executing the setup () followed by loop ().

Comment: Most ir protocols have a long initial pre-amble, before the data part to allow settle time for waking up. Where sherrif's already learned protocols require this in entirety. And as you noted it will be partial, at first. Where sherrif's ir library could be adjusted for this.

Comment: My thougt was to wake up from the intitial space (pre-amble) and start so that timer1 can resume. Alternatively one can tweak the lib to  either go back to sleep if no ir is present otherwise stay wake. This will only be awake for a moment every 50ms. This will extend life a long time (years). Many systems do such.

Comment: I still didn't get your answer because the commentaries here seems to me (Im very noob on this) that you cant use that library for this?

Comment: could anyone (sorry for asking) can write some dummy code to get the idea?